# How to get the text before the current selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a VBA macro for Word that inserts a field at the position of the cursor. The type of field shall depend on the text directly preceding the cursor. I find it surprisingly hard to access that text.

Here is what I've tried:

```
MsgBox "Text before selection: " & ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Start - 10, Selection.Start).Text
```

This works fine in the main text but fails in other parts of the document (headers, footers, text frames, ...). The reason is that the range created by `ActiveDocument.Range` points to the main story range. Is there a way to create a `Range` for the story range of the `Selection`?

Answer (score 1):

`Selection.Range` is the already the method you are looking for: It creates a new `Range` object in the same story range as the selection. Store that `Range` in a variable and update its `Start` and `End` property to get the adjacent text.

This code gets the text before the selection, no matter which part of the document is selected:

```
Dim oRng As Range
Set oRng = Selection.Range
With oRng
    .End = .Start
    .Start = .Start - 10
    MsgBox "Text before selection: " & .Text
End With
```

Another option for updating both the `Start` and `End` property at once is the [`SetRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.setrange) method.

---

Update: Through the `With` keyword, it is even possible to spare the variable declaration and assignment. I.e. this also works (but makes it harder to understand, how many objects are involved):

```
With Selection.Range
    .SetRange .Start - 10, .Start
    MsgBox "Text before selection: " & .Text
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the text before the Selection, without moving the Selection, you could use:

```
With Selection.Range.Duplicate
    .SetRange .Start - 10, .Start
    MsgBox "Text before selection: " & .Text
End With
```

Alternatively, for something more meaningful than the preceding 10 characters (e.g. the preceding two words), you might use something like:

```
With Selection.Range.Duplicate
  .End = .Words.First.Start
  .MoveStart wdWord, -2
  MsgBox "Text before selection: " & .Text
End With
```

Comment: The `Duplicate` method is an interesting pointer, but it isn't necessary. `Selection.Range.SetRange` doesn't update the selection.